# Color Specific columns based on condition of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I'm trying to colour columns `"Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6"` based on `Col1` and return other columns without any colour.

**Sample Data**

```
from random import randint

x = [randint(0, 1) for p in range(0, 10)]

sample_dict = {"Col1": [randint(0, 1) for p in range(0, 10)],
               "Col2": [randint(0, 1) for p in range(0, 10)],
               "Col3": [randint(0, 1) for p in range(0, 10)],
               "Col4": [randint(0, 1) for p in range(0, 10)],
               "Col5": [randint(0, 1) for p in range(0, 10)],
               "Col6": [randint(0, 1) for p in range(0, 10)]}
abcd = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
sample = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
```

```
data = pd.concat([sample, abcd], axis=1)
```

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   1   1   0   1   -1.358769   -0.310314   -1.056405   -0.567577
1   0   1   0   1   1   0   -0.539893   -0.139629   0.270759    -0.430564
2   1   1   1   0   1   0   -0.009886   0.023482    0.966884    0.612875
3   0   1   1   1   0   1   0.962987    0.191210    -0.228937   -0.338486
4   1   1   1   0   0   1   -0.867326   -0.461046   0.832390    0.956392
5   0   0   0   0   1   1   0.348276    0.711152    -1.016820   0.394526
6   1   1   1   1   0   0   0.622317    0.519261    -2.022494   -1.170836
7   0   1   0   0   1   0   0.033249    0.491181    -0.065532   0.936868
8   1   0   0   1   1   1   1.064310    -0.257726   -0.197229   0.348314
9   0   1   0   1   1   0   0.017713    -0.624656   -0.341611   -1.433317
```

So far, I'm able to colour it by

```
data["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6"].style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: orange" if v != x.iloc[0] else "background_color: none" for v in x], axis=1)
```

[image]

but unable to return the other columns.

How to add colour to columns `"Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6"` based on `Col1`? Iss it possible to apply different color for each column in `"Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate per column and use a dictionary of colors:

```
colors = {'Col2': 'orange',
          'Col3': 'lightblue',
          'Col4': 'lightgreen',
          'Col5': 'lightpink',
          'Col6': 'yellow'
         }

import numpy as np
(data
 .style.apply(lambda c: np.where(sample['Col1'].eq(c),
                                 'background-color: none',
                                f'background-color: {colors.get(c.name, "none")}')
             )
)
```

output:

[image: table]

Comment: @Pluviophile I already updated the answer ;) (but this was already demonstrating the effect with Col1)

Comment: Yes it maps the colors from the dictionary for the defined columns and uses no color instead

Comment: I have large data, Just wanted to check the code only looks for keys/columns that are defined in the dictionary right?

Comment: No, it will currently evaluate all columns and set None, but if you want open a new question to not pollute this one (I thought the main topic was the multiple colors) and I can provide an alternative

Comment: Could you please provide an alternate here?